# Should I bother using Ubuntu for work when everyone else is using Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

I've just started a new job and I've stayed with Linux because it's the OS I prefer. However the rest of the team uses Windows.

I'm running into problems like where I can't execute `.sh` files from the project because they've been coded with the Windows way of handling newlines and such (I would have to modify the characters to execute in Ubuntu). Is it worth it staying with Ubuntu if I have to be modifying files all the time so that I can use them on Ubuntu and them on Windows?

I'm also running into another problem connecting to the VPN of the company, which I think would be straight-forward using Windows, because they have the documentation set up.

My only objection to using Windows is that it's the laptop provided by my company and it has already TeamViewer set up, which I can't uninstall or modify. And I don't feel comfortable knowing that they can spy on me.

Comment: You might be better asking this on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/, it might get more traction.

Comment: Teamviewer is not a spy tool. There is no way that it can be used without you giving your OK to the connection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The short answer, in my opinion, is - no.

Depending on the tasks of your team, it's a constant back and forth between the different operating systems.

Selected tasks can certainly be done under Ubuntu, e.g. writing code for scripts with a text editor. But quick debugging is of course more practical in a unified development environment within your new company.

You should have an open discussion in your company's team about how to proceed.